# "Subquery has multiple rows for like comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, osisoft

I have one table give below.

[image]

In the following query, the outer query joins on a `like` comparison on the `tag` column with the subquery.

```
 SELECT top 6 *
  FROM [piarchive].[picomp2]
  WHERE tag Like
  (
  Select distinct left(tag,19) + '%' 
  from (SELECT  *
  FROM [piarchive].[picomp2]
  WHERE tag like '%CPU_Active' and  time between '2014/10/02 15:13:08'and'2014/10/02 15:18:37'
  and value=-524289 order by time desc) as t1
  )  
  and tag not like '%CPU_Active' and tag not like '%Program%' and time between '2014/10/02    
  15:13:08'and'2014/10/02 15:18:37'  order by time desc
```

But this subquery returns multiple rows, causing the following error:

> Error : "When used as an expression, subquery can return at most one row."

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` doesn't guarantee that only a single row will be returned. It only helps ensure that each of the returned rows will be "distinct". There may be thousands of "distinct" rows, all of them different (distinct) from the others.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `where tag like (...)` (where `...` is the subquery, omitted here for brevity) part with `where exists (...)`, and bring the `like` comparison into the subquery.

---

```
select top 6
    *
from
    [piarchive].[picomp2] t0
where
    exists
    (
        select
            *
        from
            (
                select
                    *
                from
                    [piarchive].[picomp2]
                where
                    tag like '%cpu_active' and time between '2014/10/02 15:13:08' and '2014/10/02 15:18:37'
                    and
                    value = -524289
            )
            as t1
        where
            t0.tag like left(t1.tag, 19) + '%' 
    ) 
    and
    tag not like '%cpu_active'
    and
    tag not like '%program%'
    and
    time between '2014/10/02 15:13:08' and '2014/10/02 15:18:37'
order by
    time desc;
```

I've added a table alias to the outer query to disambiguate the `tag` columns, but you can see the `like` comparison is shifted to within the subquery.

I can't vouch for how this will perform on large data sets, but that's a different topic. Personally, I would be looking for a way to get rid of the subquery altogether, since it's all querying the same table.

## More on optimisation

It's not going to be easy to optimise, and indexes will be of little use here, for the following reasons:

- The join criteria (`t0.tag like left(t1.tag, 19) + '%'`) is not simple, and the query optimiser may have a hard time producing anything better than nested loops (i.e., ***executing the subquery for every row of the outer query***). This is probably your biggest performance killer right here.
- None of the `like` comparisons can utilise table indexes, because they are checking the *end* of the value, not the *start*.

Your only hope might be if the date-range check is highly selective (eliminates a lot of records). Since the same check on the `time` field is performed in both outer and inner queries, you could select that into a temp table:

```
select left(tag, 19) as key, *
  into #working
  from [piarchive].[picomp2]
 where [time] between '2014/10/02 15:13:08' and '2014/10/02 15:18:37';
```

`#working` now has only the records in the specified time period. Since your example range is quite narrow (only 5 1/2 minutes), I'd wager this might knock out ~99% of records. An index on `time` will speed this up significantly. After you do this, you're only dealing with a tiny fraction of the data.

Then, possibly (see later) index `key`:

```
create clustered index cx_key on #working (key);
```

Then complete the rest of the query as:

```
select a.*
  from #working a
 where exists
       (
           select *
             from #working b
            where a.key = b.key and b.tag like '%cpu_active'
       )
       and
       a.tag not like '%program%'
       and
       a.tag not like '%cpu_active'
```

What I've done is create a clustered index on the joining criteria (the first 19 chars of `tag`) to optimise the subquery. You'll have to test this out, as it may make no difference or even slow things down if the gains are outweighed by the cost in creating the index in the first place. This will depend on how much data you have, and other factors. I only got minimal gains by doing this (about a 5% speed increase), though I'm only running this against a few hundred rows of test data I knocked up. The more data you have, the more effective it should be.

Comment: how to execute all these queries ?is it should be in sequence?

Comment: Yep, just in sequence. I would first try running the 2 `select` statements without messing around with indexes. If they run fast enough for your requirements then you can stop there. If not, add the index on the `#working` temp table as shown, and see what difference that makes.

Comment: if I am running 2 select statements then its giving error :[SQL Parser] [Line 2] Syntax error near 'into'.

Comment: I don't think this #working temp table is in correct form of syntax.both select queries are giving error when I run both simultaneously.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? These are working examples on 2008 Express.

Comment: basically this is PI database ,very similar to the sql server.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with this PI database, and can't really help with the differences between it and MSSQL.

Comment: I think only difference is temp file #working , rest of all is working fine.it doesn't understand #working in query.

Comment: That's a shame, because the temp table is crucial for the performance.

Comment: yes really ,its shame. Even I am also using this database first time.

Comment: Well, I did my best. Good luck with speeding up your query.